# How to specify compression for custom build environment in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How do I specify compression, bundling and adding invalidation hashes to filenames for a custom environment?

The production environment will automatically compress and consolidate files and add invalidation hashes to the file names. I.e. whenever I use `ember build --environment=production` to trigger the `if (environment === 'production'){}` case in `config/environment.js`

But I want to create and build for a QA environment that also compresses files and adds invalidation hashes to file names. I.e. the following should also produce compressed files named with invalidation hashes (output the same as what `production` outputs except with QA variables, like URLs):

**config/environment.js**

```
if (environment === `qa`){
    ENV.somevar = 'qa-value'
}
```

**command**

```
ember build --environment=qa
```

Comment: Why not just use the production build for this?

Comment: Ember does not fully support adding new environments. In fact, your `qa` environment is treated as `development`, so you'll have build without minification and with all debugging features. There is a workaround, I described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764150/2948109).

You can also try [ember-cli-deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/docs/v1.0.x/configuration/) addon, but I think it's a bit complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is configured in `ember-cli-build.js` file of your project. By default fingerprinting is only enabled in production (`app.env === 'production'`). This could be changed by `fingerprint.enabled` option. The same applies to `ember-cli-uglify` for JavaScript minification and `minifyCSS` options. Configure these options as required:

```
'use strict';

const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let env = EmberApp.env();
  let isProductionLike = ['production', 'qa'].includes(env);
  let app = new EmberApp({
    'ember-cli-uglify': {
      enabled: isProductionLike
    },
    fingerprint: {
      enabled: isProductionLike
    },
    minifyCSS: {
      enabled: isProductionLike
    },
    sourcemaps: {
      enabled: !isProductionLike
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

`ember-cli-uglify` option was named `minifyJS` in ember-cli-uglify 1.x. The addon was updated in default blueprint of ember-cli 2.16. Change option name accordingly if you are still using ember-cli-uglify@1.x. At the point of time writing this answer, ember-cli docs had not yet reflected that breaking change. It was introduced [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/pull/49). Also note that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/7445) about it, so it might change in the future again.

More details and options are available in [asset compilation chapter of ember-cli docs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation).

Comment: It is close but not giving me the exact same results as `environment=production`. I've enabled fingerprint, minifyCSS and minifyJS. I've also disabled sourcemaps and tests. However, the javascript is not completely uglified and minified (there's still formatting and whitespace) and I get some source maps of third party js libraries.

Comment: @gy.om Updated my answer. There was a breaking change introduced in ember-cli 2.16 which has changed option name to control minifaction of JavaScript assets. Docs of ember-cli are outdated about that point.

Comment: Seems to work great. Given the limitations of Ember-CLI, out of all the materials I've scoured online this seems to be the best workaround for this type of scenario. Wish I could vote up twice.